# Error String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been trying to create tables and add data into but I've run into this error

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 35
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Speakers_photos
(
    SpeakerID   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Image       VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(SpeakerID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SpeakerID) REFERENCES Speakers(SpeakerID)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

INSERT INTO Speakers_photos VALUES('S001210001', 0)
```

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Im having trouble reproducing your error with the data you have provided... is this the insert that is raising the error? or is it just a sample of your insert statement?

Comment: Yes, the insert is raising that error.

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 35
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: how do you define the speakerID column on the Speakers table? is it also CHAR(10)?

Comment: Yes it is CHAR(10) too

Answer (score 0):

The truncation error will not occur with the code provided.  Either the script is incomplete or the error is in an INSERT trigger on the Speakers_photos table.  In the case of a trigger, look at line 35 as indicated in the error message.